# Javascript Error in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

There are two instances of Javascript failing through Safari. It's only safari, I've tested on multiple machines with different versions.

I have a large form, at one point in the form, they submit via AJAX (don't worry it's all validated and safe to send). I pick the information up using this method:

```
var vcompany = document.forms['registerForm']['vcompany'].value;
```

This doesn't seem to work. Also, in another instance I am picking information up from a form and calculating based on that information, then outputting it as a total price. This also does not seem to work:

```
var dates_A =  document.forms['registerForm']['childADates[]']; //from a checkbox group
```

Does anybody know of any issues? I'm not getting an error, the commands just aren't firing...

Comment: How do you register errors in Safari?

Comment: On this occasion, the fact that the form doesn't work - I'll do some error checking and post the messages now

Comment: Could you post the HTML for the relevant elements?  What kind of element is vcompany, or childADates?

Comment: thanks but I sussed it :) Cheers for your help anyway. I've posted my solution as an answer lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is one of the key moments of stupidity in my life... I had a variable named class which all browsers accepted but Safari would not, it is a reserved word. The moment of stupidity: not checking the error log.

Comment: @Daniel But where is the error log in Safari? How do you check it?

Comment: Click Develop in the toolbar along the top of the screen and then click Show Error Log

Comment: @Daniel I don't have the "Develop" item in my toolbar. You must be using a plug-in or something ...

Comment: Nope: Version 5.0.3 (6533.19.4) on OSX

Comment: @Daniel It could be that the Mac version of Safari has features that are not in the Win version (I'm on Win 7)...

Comment: Apparently you enable it in the Advanced preferences. A simple google brought that up

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you are getting references to the form elements via document.forms?

You should get better cross browser results by either document.getElementById() or document.getElementsByTagName().

```
//if you have the same id's as the input's "name" attribute
var vcompany = document.getElementById('vcompany').value;//text input
var dates_A =  document.getElementById('childADates[]').checked;//checkbox
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: Cheers but unfortunately the problem was unrelated to the way I was picking the information from the form, See my answer